# How do you filter out or not include certain records in a model admin multiselect widget in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How do you filter out or not include certain records in a model admin multi-select widget.  For example a recursive relationship will include edited or added field to the multi-select widget but should not include its exact self,

```
class A(models.Model):
   b = models.CharField()
   a = models.ManyToManyField('self')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an attr to do so: `limit_choices_to`

```
class A(models.Model):
   a = models.ManyToManyField('self', limit_choices_to={<condition>})
```

Comment: so how does work for a and b field? limit to a's where a not equal to b.

Comment: try `limit_choices_to={id__in != self.id }` for all A objects that are not the operating A object.